# How do I use XML as a DataSource for a DataGridView in a WinForms project?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, datagridview

How do I link an editable DataGridView to an XML file in a WinForms project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way recommended by MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx  is to load it into a data set.

> Q Can you tell me the best way to bind XML data to a DataGridView control?
>
> A The simplest possible solution is to load the XML into a DataSet and bind to that. Another solution would be to use XML serialization to create an object graph from the XML and bind to that. To bind to the raw XML, you would need to create wrapper classes that implement ITypedList, IBindingList, and ICustomTypeDescriptor.

There is an entire set of code over at DevX here and a tutorial that might help you with binding DataGridView to XML via data sets. http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28678/1954

Hope this helps.