# Retrieving data from XML file into GridView

Tags: c#, xml

i have retrieved Data from xml file and displayed it in gridview using C#, but i want to show all data including the inner tags here is my C# code:

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("D:\\ab.xml");

DataSet ds = new DataSet("Books DataSet");
ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "CP";
```

and this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
<Permission>
    <CP name="Student">
        <tab name="studentinfo"></tab>
        <tab name="notes">
        <groupbox name="ss">
            <field type="textArea" x="xxx" />
        </groupbox>
        </tab>
    </CP>
    <CP name="Teacher"></CP>
    <CP name="doctor"></CP>
</Permission>
```

i want after it shows data of `<CP>` it shows data of `<tab>` then `<groupbox>` etc if any confusion please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not between the XML and gridview but between the XML and dataset.
see [how-do-i-use-xml-as-a-datasource-for-a-datagridview-in-a-winforms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265604/how-do-i-use-xml-as-a-datasource-for-a-datagridview-in-a-winforms-project) and [import-xml-into-dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894451/import-xml-into-dataset-c/902518#902518) for a discussion of how to parse XML into a dataset.