# xml deserialize and load datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to make an xml file and load the contents into a datagridview. From what I've read i should be able to do a simple

```
datagrid1.DataSource = cars;
```

but for some reason it's not showing anything in my datagridview.  I am using as a trial this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/364401/933552) to see if I can make it work.  I wasn't sure if I should post all the code in here aswell or if the link is sufficient.  If needed I can copy/paste that code here.  If not can anyone point me in the right direction?

Class cars.cs

```
[Serializable()]
public class Car
{
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("StockNumber")]
 public string StockNumber { get; set; }

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Make")]
 public string Make { get; set; }

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Model")]
 public string Model { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("CarCollection")]
public class CarCollection
{
  [XmlArray("Cars")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Car", typeof(Car))]
  public Car[] Car { get; set; }
}
```

Form

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarCollection cars = null;
        string path = "c://cars.xml";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarCollection));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        cars = (CarCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();


        // finally bind the data to the grid
        dataGridView1.DataSource = cars;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To populate a datagridview you need to [set the datasource and then get the data (example on MSDN shows getting from a database, but an xml source is not that different)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx).  Without seeing your code I'm not sure, but are you doing the second step?

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265604/how-do-i-use-xml-as-a-datasource-for-a-datagridview-in-a-winforms-project) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

sorry figured it out I had to do this:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = cars.Car;
```