# Using stored procedure For XML Path read directly into DataSet bound to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[usp_GetMyAlbumData]  
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[tblAlbumDetails]  
    FOR XML PATH('AlbumDetail'), ROOT('AlbumDetails'), TYPE
```

and I need to figure out how to use the XML produced by `usp_ReportGetMyAlbumData` to display the data in a datagridview.

For example, I have one record in my database. When I run the `usp_ReportGetMyAlbumData` stored procedure in SQL Server 2012, I get the following results:

```
<AlbumDetails>
  <AlbumDetail>
    <MusicID>1</MusicID>
    <AlbumDesc>Jones</AlbumDesc>
    <AlbumDate>2018-10-13T15:55:49.843</AlbumDate>
    <AlbumPrice>4.0000</AlbumPrice>
  </AlbumDetail>
</AlbumDetails>
```

I'd like to use C# to write this XML result (or any other XML results produced by `usp_ReportGetMyAlbumData`) to a DataSet so that I can bind it to a DataGridView.

I know how to [write XML files to a Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/read-xml-data-into-a-dataset?view=vs-2017) but the stored procedure returns XML, not an XML *file*.

What code do I need to write to populate the dataset with the data in the XML produced by the stored procedure?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL server 2012

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468566/xml-deserialize-and-load-datagridview ?

Comment: @lex87 I'm sorry I'm still confused.  I'm looking at the answer in the link and it says that binding xml sources is not much different than binding to database sources, but it is quite different because the xml output is a string and the dataset is a different structure.  The links that amelvin puts in his answer forward to another question that has expired links and one link to a webinar-on-demand that uses vb code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml will be a string from the database.  So I would use xml linq parse method to take string a put into a datatable.  Then make the datatable the source of the DGV.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //data will be from the database a string
            //I'm reading fron a file for testing
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("MusicID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("AlbumDesc", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AlbumDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("AlbumPrice", typeof(decimal));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            foreach(XElement album in doc.Descendants("AlbumDetail"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (int)album.Element("MusicID"),
                    (string)album.Element("AlbumDesc"),
                    (DateTime)album.Element("AlbumDate"),
                    (decimal)album.Element("AlbumPrice")
                });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the code you posted, I get no rows or row headers on the DataGridView.  When I go into debug mode and check the DataTable, it has 4 columns and 1 row.  The data in the DataTable is correct before setting it as the datasource of the DataGridView, but nothing appears.  The only difference is that instead of using a file, I used a string with \n after each end tag to separate the lines.

Comment: try setting the DataSource to null before setting to dt.  The DGV repaint method doesn't automatically get called when you change the datasource.  So the trick is to set to null so the DGV gets updated.  Very common issue.  Xml ignores white spaces so the '\n' is optional.  There is no reason you have to format the DGV before calling my code.  The code will automaticaly creates the columns and make the data types match the datatable.

Comment: dgvMusic.DataSource = null;
            dgvMusic.DataSource = dt;
Didn't work either.

Comment: Creating a new datagridview worked!  I don't understand why it worked, but it did.  What could have caused the problem?

Comment: A blank DGV will automatically do all the work.  An existing one may have incompatible settings with the datatable.

Answer (score 2):

```
string xml = "your xml here";
var ds = new DataSet();

using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    ds.ReadXml(reader);
}

dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: unfortunately, this also isn't producing anything in the DataGridView.  I do like how simple it is though.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @ArmorCode - This is guaranteed to work (as is the other answer). Make sure you are binding the data to the correct DataGridView.

Comment: This also works now as does the other answer.  I just needed to delete and recreate the datagridview as jdweng said.