# read xml root node into datagrid and write edits back to xml file

Tags: c#, xml

```
        this.dataGrid1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid();
        this.dataGrid1.DataMember = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        this.dataGrid1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 46);
        this.dataGrid1.Name = "dataGrid1";
        this.dataGrid1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(364, 532);
        this.dataGrid1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(592, 573);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.dataGrid1 });
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGrid1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);


        XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("abcd.xml");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("abc");
        ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;

        dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
```

It is showing the hierarchial structure but it is not distinguishing between the child and parent node properly.i only want to see the root node which should be a link to its child node.also,i want the datagrid to be able to edit the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the Xml in DataSet why dont you set the DataTable rather than the whole DataSet as DataSource of the Grid ?

```
    XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("abcd.xml");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("abc");
    ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;

    dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Adjust the Table index with your appropriate Root table.

Comment: this works.now can u please tell me how to edit the datagrid so that the corresponding values in xml can be edited?

Comment: Does this help : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9697/Edit-Almost-Anything-in-a-DataGrid

BTW, you need to get xml from the DataTable again after update.

Comment: This link doesnt help.actually at the time of pgm run i want to edit the data grid so that changed values can be reflected in xml file.

Comment: How about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265604/how-do-i-use-xml-as-a-datasource-for-a-datagridview-in-a-winforms-project

Answer (score 1):

to write any edits back to the xml file use the following:

```
DataSet ds= ((DataTable)datagrid1.dataSource).DataSet; 
//this statement populates the dataset.
//which is reflected in xml file as-- 
ds.WriteXml(s, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema); 
ds.AcceptChanges();
```