# Edit XML file through DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [show only root node in data grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832321/show-only-root-node-in-data-grid)

```
        this.dataGrid1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid();
        this.dataGrid1.DataMember = "";
        this.dataGrid1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 50);
        this.dataGrid1.Name = "dataGrid1";
        this.dataGrid1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(464, 432);
        this.dataGrid1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(592, 573);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.dataGrid1 });
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGrid1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);


        XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("abcd.xml");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("abc");
        ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;

        dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Above code reads the XML file and displays in DataGrid. Can somebody tell me how to edit the DataGrid so that the corresponding values in XML can be edited?

Answer (score 0):

XML and Datagrid Dataset are not interlinked, so u need to do it manually by writing the XML from Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

To save changes from the `DataSet` back to the XML file you would simply have to do

```
     ds.Tables[0] = (DataTable)(dataGrid1.DataSource);
     ds.WriteXml("your path here");
```

As a side note, your code is slightly redundant. When you create an instance of `XmlDataDocument`, you could just access it's `DataSet` property without creating a new `DataSet` instance as your code shows. If you just want to read an XML file into a `DataSet` you could do the following

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("abc");
    ds.ReadXml("abcd.xml");

    dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: file is being modified but the changes are not reflected.

Comment: @akanki Answer modified.

Comment: ds.Tables[0] = (DataTable)(dataGrid1.DataSource)...is this line working correctly on your side as dis is showing error  ErrorProperty or indexer 'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: i have found the answer finally....

DataSet ds= ((DataTable)datagrid1.dataSource).DataSet;

this statement populates the dataset.which is reflected in xml file as--

ds.WriteXml(s, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
ds.AcceptChanges();